# How do I tell if an empty line has been read in with a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io, whitespace, bufferedreader

I'm reading in a text file formated like

```
word
definiton

word
definition
definition

word
definition
```

So I need to keep try of whether I'm in a definition or not based on when I reach those emtpy lines. Thing is, `BufferedReader` discards `\n` characters, and somehow comparing that empty line to `String ""` is not registering like I thought it would. How can I go about doing this.

Comment: Please do not put tags in titles.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Make sure you use: `"".equals(myString)` (which is `null`-safe) not `myString == ""`.

   - After 1.6, you can use `myString.isEmpty()` (not `null`-safe)
2. You can use `myString.trim()` to get rid of extra whitespace before the above check

Here's some code:

```
public void readFile(BufferedReader br) {
  boolean inDefinition = false;
  while(br.ready()) {
    String next = br.readLine().trim();
    if(next.isEmpty()) {
      inDefinition = false;
      continue;
    }
    if(!inDefinition) {
      handleWord(next);
      inDefinition = true;
    } else {
      handleDefinition(next);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if 1.6 or greater, use [`String#isEmpty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29).

Comment: you trimming it get rid of white space in the middle of the string? Because these are defintions like "red blue green" I dont want them to become "redbluegreen"

Comment: trim() only removes characters `<= ' '` at the start and the end.  It will not remove all white space but it will remove control characters.

Comment: Thank you, this really cleared up my confusion over this. I had to add some extra code in the block where the string ends up empty to handle the completed String of the multi-line definition.

Answer (score 6):

The `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns an empty string if the line is empty.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) says:

> Returns:  A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached.

If you don't appear to be seeing an empty String, either the line is not empty, or you are not testing for an empty String correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
line = reader.readLine();
if ("".equals(line)) {
   //this is and empty line...
}
```

I do not know how did you try to check that string is empty, so I cannot explain why it did not work for you. Did you probably use `==` for comparison? In this case it did not work because `==` compares references, not the object content.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippets skips the empty line and only prints the ones with content.

```
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.trim().equals("")) {
            // empty line
        } else {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Lines only containing whitespace characters are also skipped.

Answer (score -2):

```
try (BufferedReader originReader = getReader("now")) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(originReader.readLine())) {
        System.out.printline("Buffer is empty");
    }
```